# Kivy is not showing a GUI or errors on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python-2.7, kivy, raspberry-pi3

I have here a raspberry PI 3 with Kivy 1.9.2. and Python 2.7 on it. After some tinkering, the installation works fine but I can't get it to display anything. I tried to make a basic "hello world" button, but the program is stuck in the terminal.

This is what I get on my screen (The "INFO" is always green):

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/pi/.kivy/logs/kivy_16-11-15_2.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.2-dev0
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v2.7.9 (default, Sep 17 2016, 20:26:04) 
[GCC 4.9.2]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 193 symbols loaded
```

.... < More INFO in between

it ends with:

```
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
```

This is the code I used, it is saved on the desktop as a .py file. On that same desktop I am able to run other .py scripts without any troubles. (the '`#`' on the first line is not to comment that line out, it is a bang or something like that and it is supposed to be there.):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.2')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class Test(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text="Hello world",
                      background_color=(1, 0, 0, 1),
                      font_size = 120)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Test().run()
```

As said in the title, the terminal isn't giving an error, but neither is there a button displayed.

If I run this script in the IDLE > run > run module, the same happens; when I then try close IDLE it gives a pop up message:
"The program is still running! Do you want to kill it?" (Ok / Cancel).

This indicates that the button itself is running, somehow, but not displaying.

Comment: did you see the log file? `/home/pi/.kivy/logs/kivy_16-11-15_2.txt`

Comment: Yes, Every time I ran a script, that log file stored the exact same things in there as the output that was generated in my LXTerminal.

Comment: works for me on Raspberry Pi 3, Kivy 1.9.1 Python3.5.2

Comment: are you sure you had a clean installation?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution to it:

I didn't bother reflashing the SD with the original Raspbian OS, I just kept working on the same system for this solution.

In the Raspberry Pi menu's I went to the UI used to add programs and packages, just searched there for Kivy, installed it from there.

Then ran all Raspbian updates again (sudo apt-get clean; sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade). Rebooted the Pi and now it works... Thanks everyone for your time and suggestions. I hope this solution will work for future users.